# Why can't QGIS connect to remote PostGIS installed on an Amazon-Lightsail VM?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I've setup a local installation of PostGIS in the past, and had no problem connecting QGIS to it in Localhost. However, I recently rented an Amazon Lightsail Ubuntu virtual machine to make my PostGIS database available remotely, and I can't figure out how to connect QGIS to it.

**Possible problem #1:** One of the big differences I noticed between installing PostgreSQL/PostGIS locally with the installer (from https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads), and with the command lines (`apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib` and `apt-get install postgis`) is that, with the former, the installer asked me for a 'postgres' superuser password, and no password was asked to me in command line. Hence, when I try to connect to PostGIS in QGIS, the password part is a mystery.

I therefor looked at how to setup a password with the command `\password` and restarted the server, but QGIS still can't connect:
[image]

**Possible problem #2:** 
I looked for a solution and found this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466190/cant-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432. Which suggests to modify the file `postgresql.conf` and set this parameter as such: `listen_addresses = '*'`.

However, I'm not sure where to find this file in my Amazon Lightsail VM. Also, this seems like a "hacky" solution. Has anyone had this kind of problems before? Is there a trick I'm overseeing? In short: what's the proper way to fix this?

Comment: open port 5432 on lightsail > https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/understanding-firewall-and-port-mappings-in-amazon-lightsail

Comment: I opened the port, thanks! It still shows the same error, but I'm sure this port opening was part of the issue, so that's probably one less roadblock!

Comment: if on linux would use telnet to test the ip/port connection https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-and-use-telnet-on-ubuntu-1804/

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the solution is around your possible solution #2.

If you don't modify your postgres.conf, PostgreSQL/PostGIS won't accept connections outside of localhost. If adding `listen addresses = "*"` to your conf seems unsafe or hacky, you can add your own IP instead, if it's somewhat static.

Here are few different options on how to locate your postgres.conf file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602450/where-are-my-postgres-conf-files